# Sorting vector of different class objects based on their member variables

Tags: c++, class

Let's say I have a code like this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#using namespace std;

class animal{
protected:
int height;
int speed;
};

class horse:public animal{
public:
horse(){
  height=200;
  speed=75;
 }
};
class cat:public animal{
public:
cat(){
    height=30;
    speed=20;
 }
};
class dog:public animal{
public:
 dog(){
    height=55;
    speed=35;
  }
};

int main() {
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<animal>>animalvector;
animalvector.emplace_back((unique_ptr<animal>(new horse)));
animalvector.emplace_back((unique_ptr<animal>(new cat)));
animalvector.emplace_back((unique_ptr<animal>(new dog)));

return 0;
}
```

I want to sort this animalvector in a descending order based on the speed of these different animals. What's the best method to do it?

Comment: [`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort)?

Comment: OT: Note that your program has undefined behavior, since the destructors in your class hierarchy are not virtual. Objects created by `new horse`, `new cat`, and `new dog` are destructed by `~animal()`.

Comment: Aside: There's no point in `class horse` `class cat` `class dog` etc if they only differ in initial value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `std::sort` from `<algorithm>` with a lambda function define your sorting predicate.

```
std::sort(animalvector.begin(),
          animalvector.end(),
          [](auto const& lhs, auto const& rhs)
{
     return lhs->speed > rhs->speed;
});
```

Note that `speed` would either need to be `public` or you'd need a public getter function. If you wanted to add getter methods

```
class animal
{
public:
    int GetHeight() const { return height; }
    int GetSpeed() const { return speed; }
protected:
    int height;
    int speed;
};
```

then you'd modify the lambda to use these getters

```
std::sort(animalvector.begin(),
          animalvector.end(),
          [](auto const& lhs, auto const& rhs)
{
     return lhs->GetSpeed() > rhs->GetSpeed();
});
```

Comment: Since I'm a new learner I don't have much experience using sorting algorithms.Can you please show me how do I use getter function in std::sort?

Comment: @Draxes I've updated my answer to demonstrate how you could do that.